# Electron storing files internally

Tags: javascript, electron

**Question :** I want my electron app to have a built-in 3d model, what would be the best way to go about it?

I am currently storing it in the dist/models/foot.babylon.When the app is opened I want to load a file in. I tried using `fetch('/models/foot.babylon')`, but that didn't work.

My folder structure.

```
├──.babelrc
├──.eslintrc
├──.flowconfig
├──.gitignore
├──LICENSE
├──README.md
├──dist
│  ├──bundle.css
│  ├──bundle.js
│  ├──index.html
│  └──models
│     ├──foot.babylon
├──main.js
├──package-lock.json
├──package.json
├──src
│  ├──actions
│  │  ├──files.js
│  │  ├──index.js
│  │  └──types.js
│  ├──components
│  ├──containers
│  │  ├──Analyser
│  │  ├──App
│  │  ├──Header
│  │  └──LiveData
│  ├──engines
│  │  ├──RenderEngine.js
│  │  └──Scene.js
│  ├──helpers
│  ├──index.js
│  ├──menu.js
│  ├──reducers
│  ├──routes.js
│  └──store
│     └──index.js
├──template.ejs
├──tools
├──webpack.build.config.js
├──webpack.dev.config.js
└──yarn.lock
```

I could possibly import it as a string to one of my .js files, but the file size at least 10mb, so it would be slow for bundling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) you could create a splash screen when assets load since fs is asynchronous.

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + "/models/foot.babylon", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log(data);
        // Process file data
        // Remove splash screen and show app
    }
});
```

Comment: Where would the file be stored when the application is bundled?

Comment: When you build the app the `models` directory should be bundled with your app. If you are asking about the location so you can read them you can just use [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html) like in my example, this will return the location of the current file your in.